# Getting the local instance of SQL Server rather than a named instance

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

A while ago, I wrote a web-based guestbook application that wrote it's own database.

My code was very amateurish, but, as it was my very first publication, I was very happy with it.
Only about a month after I'd published it did I realize I'd made a huge mistake in the code.

I've only ever connected to a specific named instance of SQL Server, and it occurred to me that, if the SQL Server instance has a different name than the one I specified, it wouldn't work.

So, since my users will probably not know what the name of the instance of SQL Server that's running is, I thought adding a field where the user can specify it would help if they do, but what if they don't?
My answer was to get the local instance, regardless of name.

I tried `Data Source=.\local;`, `Data Source=.;` and other variants, but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-named instance is called "default instance" and can be accessed using `"Data Source=(local);..."`.

Comment: I don't think I tried that one, thanks :) Only issue is I'm getting `Could not open a connection to SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

The only way of knowing which instances are running is by querying the SQL Browser Service, if it's running.
I guess most of your users are running SQL Server Express? If so, the service is called local\SQLEXPRESS. If not, it's local or they've named it themselves. So, I would try local\SQLEXPRESS first, then local. If none works, just throw an exception and ask the user to add it themselves.

Comment: The big problem is that I can never know anything about their system (what version of SQL Server they're running included).
As I said, I thought of adding a field for the user to type in the name of his/her SQL Server instance, but what happens if they don't know it?

Comment: If the user doesn't know it's either SQLExpress or default. At least in 99.9% of the cases :-)